# python Thread.name is printing last thread created name

Tags: python, multithreading

I'm a newbie to Python and learning about threads. I have created a sample Producer-Consumer code wherein I add a movie to a list in **Producer** thread and pop the front element from the same list in **Consumer** thread. The problem is while printing the items of the movie List along with thread name I'm getting incorrect thread name in **Producer** thread. This is my code

Producer.py

```
from threading import Thread
from threading import RLock
import time


class Producer(Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        Thread.name = 'Producer'

        self.movieList = list()
        self.movieListLock = RLock()


    def printMovieList(self):
        self.movieListLock.acquire()

        if len(self.movieList) > 0:
            for movie in self.movieList:
                print(Thread.name, movie)

            print('\n')

        self.movieListLock.release()


    def pushMovieToList(self, movie):
        self.movieListLock.acquire()

        self.movieList.append(movie)
        self.printMovieList()

        self.movieListLock.release()


    def run(self):
        for i in range(6):
            self.pushMovieToList('Avengers' + str(i + 1))
            time.sleep(1)
```

Consumer.py

```
from threading import Thread
import time


class Consumer(Thread):

    def __init__(self):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        Thread.name = 'Consumer'

        self.objProducer = None


    def popMovieFromList(self):
        self.objProducer.movieListLock.acquire()

        if len(self.objProducer.movieList) > 0:
            movie = self.objProducer.movieList.pop(0)
            print(Thread.name, ':', movie)
            print('\n')

        self.objProducer.movieListLock.release()


    def run(self):
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
            self.popMovieFromList()
```

Main.py

```
from Producer import *
from Consumer import *


def main():
    objProducer = Producer()
    objConsumer = Consumer()

    objConsumer.objProducer = objProducer

    objProducer.start()
    objConsumer.start()

    objProducer.join()
    objConsumer.join()


main()
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure whether you solve this problem.
Hope my answer will be helpful.
You can check the document of threading.

[Here](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.name) it says that Thread.name may set same name for multiple thread.

> **name**
>   A string used for identification purposes only. It has no semantics. Multiple threads may be given the same name. The initial name is set by the constructor.

I think Thread.name is a static variable so it shares in different thread.
If you want to set name of thread, you can set it in thread object like this:

```
class Producer(Thread):
def __init__(self):
    Thread.__init__(self)
    self.name= 'Producer'
```

and get it by threading.current_thread().name.

```
if len(self.movieList) > 0:
    for movie in self.movieList:
    print(threading.current_thread().name, movie)
```

Hope you enjoy it!